# What is the fastest way to get double[][] to a MATLAB matrix in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, matrix, octave, processbuilder

I need to use MATLAB/Octave with ProcessBuilder class in Java. I have one argument and it going to be a very very long string that are shaped as a MATLAB/Octave array.

```
[1 2 3 4;
 4 5 6 3; 
 .
 .
 .
 3 4 2 5]
```

So I begun to code where `A` is the matrix and `matA` is going to be the argument in ProcessBuilder object.

```
    String matA = "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            matA = matA + " " + A[i][j];
        }
        if(i < rows-1)
            matA = matA + ";";
    }
    matA = matA + "]";
    System.out.println(matA);
```

Like this:

```
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(matA);
        processBuilder.command("singularvaluesdecomposition.m");
        try {
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And my MATLAB/Octave file looks like this:

```
function singularvaluesdecomposition(A)
    [U, S, ~] = svd(A);
    U
    diag(S)
end
```

But building `matA` takes enormus amout of time. Is there any faster whay todo this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when changing data a lot, it is better to use StringBuilder instead of String.
Strings are immutable and changing them is done by making another object, though the user can't see that visually.

try this:

```
StringBuilder matA = new StringBuilder("[");
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        matA.append(" " + A[i][j]);
    }
    if(i < rows-1)
        matA.append(";");
}
matA.append("]");
System.out.println(matA);
```

for more info:
https://javapapers.com/java/java-string-vs-stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer-concatenation-performance-micro-benchmark/

Comment: Thanks. Much fast! But now I got another error. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spac` perhaps I should try to call Python code from Java.

Comment: increase heap size. for example if you're running your code in terminal, use: java -Xmx6g myclass

Comment: I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Is it a better way to send the double[][] array from ProcessBuilder instead?

Comment: edit or add -Xmx6g in eclipse.ini file or from gui follow https://www.planetofbits.com/eclipse/increase-jvm-heap-size-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at that!